# DataTables.js: How to re-render the table after updating a cell so the table understands that there is a new value

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am a newbie to DataTables and I encountered with a huge (for me) problem that I just don't get how to solve. Here is my live demo https://codepen.io/Balzzac/pen/mpdGgL with questions in certain places .

Let me try to explain: i have a table (id='js_table') that gets data from AJAX call (in codepen - from variable dataSet). It has 2 columns: "Assigned" and "Name". When data comes I render the first column, replacing "yes"/"no" with circles for type==="display" and with"assigned"/"not assigned" for "else", so it looks nice and provide a user the opportunity via clicking on the circle to assign or unassign a person.

When clicking on the circle (js_assign_element), JS runs a function where it replaces classes (from green to red and vice versa) as well as changing data-attributes into "assigned" when the person wasn't assigned and "not assigned" when person was. But the table itself doesn't "understand/recognize" the change, so it sorts and filters the first column like no changes were made.

```
$(document).off('click', '.js_assign_element').on('click', '.js_assign_element', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass("__assigned")) {
        $(this).removeClass("__assigned").attr("data-search", "not assigned").attr("data-filter", "not assigned").attr("data-sort", "not assigned").attr("data-order", "not assigned")
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("__assigned").attr("data-search", "assigned").attr("data-filter", "assigned").attr("data-sort", "assigned").attr("data-order", "assigned")
    }

    // Tried Following:
    // $("#js_table").DataTable().draw() - doesn't work
    // $("#js_table").DataTable().rows().invalidate("dom").draw() - doesn't work
    // $("#js_table").DataTable().rows().invalidate().draw() - doesn't work either
})
```

Can you please look and help me with my question(s)? Thanks

Comment: You are not updating attributes on the <td> but on the inner elements. Thats why it not works.

Comment: Would appreciate tremendously if you show/explain me how to update td. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should also update the array of the data. Simply change the data with new data containing the changed value.

Clear the previous table then add the modified data to the table and redraw.

```
$(document).off('click', '.js_assign_element').on('click', '.js_assign_element', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass("__assigned")) {
        $(this).removeClass("__assigned").attr("data-search", "not assigned").attr("data-filter", "not assigned").attr("data-sort", "not assigned").attr("data-order", "not assigned")
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("__assigned").attr("data-search", "assigned").attr("data-filter", "assigned").attr("data-sort", "assigned").attr("data-order", "assigned")
    }


    var test = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html();

    var setval = ($(this).hasClass('element_assign __assigned'))? 'yes' : 'no';


    $.each(dataSet, function(i,v){
        var tes = v.indexOf(test);
        // tez[i] = ['yes', test];
        if(v[1] === test){
            //console.log(v);
            //console.log(dataSet[i][0]);
        dataSet[i][0] = setval; 
        }
    })


   $('#js_table').DataTable().clear().draw();
   $('#js_table').DataTable().rows.add(dataSet); // Add new modified data
   $('#js_table').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(); // Redraw the DataTable


    // Tried Following:
    // $("#js_table").DataTable().draw() - doesn't work
    // $("#js_table").DataTable().rows().invalidate("dom").draw() - doesn't work
    // $("#js_table").DataTable().rows().invalidate().draw() - doesn't work either
})
```

See working example here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZKOzx